# I am trying to plot the function below, however, it does not seem to be working

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

Do you know what I am doing wrong? The image I put below shows the function I would like to plot.[image: mathematica]

Answer (score 2):

Remove the "underscores" in the plot-command!
Try

```
f[x_] = Integrate[(7 + 9 x)/(1 + x^2), x]
Plot[f[x],{x,-5,5}]
```

[image]